# Jacoco Mvn Plugin fails all unit tests

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

Am confused here, I am running maven 3, java 1.6 and have a maven project configured, everything works including all the unit tests. Now i come to add the Jacoco plugin, configured thus

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.5.201112152213</version>
            <configuration>
                <destfile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destfile>
                <datafile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</datafile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

now when i try to run mvn clean package none of the unit tests pass and there is no coverage report at all.

Can anyone point out where i am going wrong please?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use a mocking framework?

Comment: hi assylias, yes - apologies i forgot to mention this, there is some mockito code and some jmockit code in pretty much all of the unit tests.

Comment: I raised an issue some time ago - not sure if it is related: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/35

Comment: assylias  i switched out and used this version of JMockit, now only 1 test is failing, although i am still getting no report at all unfortunately, a step in the correct direction though.....<dependency>
   <groupId>org.dspace.dependencies.jmockit</groupId>
   <artifactId>dspace-jmockit</artifactId>
   <version>0.999.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: my solution in the end was to move to cobertura :-( Someone else might be able to help you.

Comment: `code`<version>0.5.10.201208310627</version>`code` as the version of jacoco and the version of of JMockit as stated above and now i am down to just one test failing and that is a Mockito test, i Ignore that one test and everything works properly for me..........